# How to use setCharacterStream to update Clob in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

When I used the follow snippets to update Oracle Clob:

```
     String toBeUpdated = ""
     StringReader reader = new StringReader(toBeUpdated);
     pStmt.setCharacterStream(parameterIndex,reader , toBeUpdated.length());
```

When the length of string "toBeUpdated" is a little bit bigger(general more than 5000) and a value had been ready stored into db, it was without any exceptions and the expected value was returned in method executeUpdate() when I ran the above codes. but the stranger probelm is that I checked DB and found the column was null.(it should be updated with new value).

it did not happened every time but a little bit randomly.
I tried use pStmt.setString() instead of pStmt.setCharacterStream everything was going to be fine. as far as I know setString is limited of maximize string size(63000) it cannot be proposed solution.

Is anybody can light me or experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provide Classes for store CLOB from strings. I have use the following code and it works fine:

```
    long id = ...
    String content = ... // CLOB content
    try {
        Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY_SERVER:1521:MY_DB", "user", "pass");
        String query = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_CLOB_COLUMN = ? WHERE ID = ? ";
        OraclePreparedStatement opstmt = (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(query);
        opstmt.setStringForClob(1, content);
        opstmt.setLong(2, id);
        int result = opstmt.executeUpdate();
         System.out.println("Resultado para : " + tabla + " - " + columna + "  - " +  id + ":" + result);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //Log here
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //Log here
    }
```